# PostgreSQL's array_agg() and array_to_string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, postgresql

I wonder if there's a counterpart of `array_agg()` and `array_to_string` of `PostgreSQL` in `MySQL` (Or anything close to this function at least) I haven't had any luck on my research trying to find something similar to this two. For non-PostgreSQL users, here's how it works.
Normally, executing:

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table;
```

Will result to:

```
--------------
| my_column  |
|------------|
|   DATA1    |
|   DATA2    |
|   DATA3    |
|   DATA4    |
--------------
```

On the other hand, executing the statement:

```
SELECT array_agg(my_column) FROM my_table;
```

Will result to:
A single row with all the data from my_column.

```
-----------------------------------
|       array_agg(my_column)      |
|---------------------------------|
|{"DATA1","DATA2","DATA3","DATA4"}|
-----------------------------------
```

And array_to_string, as the function name says, it converts the array into a single String.

Converting the array_agg(my_column) will return the following:

```
-------------------------
|                       |
|-----------------------|
|DATA1,DATA2,DATA3,DATA4|
-------------------------
```

Depending on your separator. In my case, it's comma.
************************************Edit(SOLUTION)********************************

Solution (Written by IgorRomanchenko):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(my_column SEPARATOR ',');
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP_CONCAT` for string aggregation?

Comment: And as for the array_to_string question – MySQL does not have an “Array” data type built-in, so asking for a similar function is rather pointless. If you just want to concatenate a number of singular values with a separator in between, look at CONCAT_WS. And in general, look at the function overview to get an idea of what functions MySQL provides and what purpose you can use them for and on which data types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/func-op-summary-ref.html

Comment: just notice, in PostgreSQL 9.0 and higher you can use string_agg function instead sequence string_to_array(array_agg(..),',') - it is a little bit faster.

Comment: @Pavel Stehule
Thanks for your input! I'll consider optimizing my procedures.

Comment: @CBroe
Thanks for sharing your knowledge on MySQL. I'll take a look on your suggested function.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko
Hi Igor, please consider answering my question with your comment so I could accept it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL does not have bult in array type, but you can use string aggregation (like `GROUP_CONCAT`) to aggregate multiple values to a single string.

Comment: If grouped string contains the separator, it can cause problem deserializing it.